# Subclass Netty Channel or use existing

Tags: serial-port, netty

We are becoming more and more dependent on Netty and have up until recently relied PureJavaCommChannel, an OioChannel implementation on built on top of PureJavaComm which is further built on JTermios. JTermios is a JNA wrapper of the Posix C libraries.

Needing more control of configuration and performance of the serial port we recently had a need to drop the PureJavaComm layer and use JTermios directly.

What would be the best way usher data to and from a channel implementation sourced/sunk by posix read/write calls? Should I subclass one of the abstract channel types or use one of the existing concrete channels? I’m currently using an EmbededChannels as a sort of two way queue for that purpose but my hunch is this is a bit of a misuse of that class. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end this sounds like you may be better of to implement your custom "transport". This would in the simplest case be an sub-class of `AbstractChannel` and an `EventLoop` / `EventLoopGroup` implementation that works with it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just go done reading your book and hoped it would cover implementing those things. Can you point me to a resource that discusses that topic?

Answer (score 0):

Well then let this be an example of a naive Oio channel.

```
public class StreamChannel extends OioByteStreamChannel {
    private final AtomicBoolean isInputShutdown = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final AtomicBoolean isOpen = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    private final InputStream input;
    private final OutputStream output;

    public StreamChannel(InputStream input, OutputStream output) {
        super(null);
        this.input = input;
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return isOpen.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isInputShutdown() {
        return isInputShutdown.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected ChannelFuture shutdownInput() {
        isInputShutdown.set(true);
        return this.newSucceededFuture();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doConnect(SocketAddress otherUnused, SocketAddress unused) throws Exception {
        activate(input, output);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doDisconnect() throws Exception {
        isOpen.set(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doBind(SocketAddress unused) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    protected SocketAddress localAddress0() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected SocketAddress remoteAddress0() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ChannelConfig config() {
        return new DefaultChannelConfig(this);
    }
}
```